# Web Server not requiring .php extension suddenly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, configuration

This is perplexing to me ...  My live site all of a sudden does not require the .php extension to be used to load the content.

this is troubling because I have **example.php** in the directory and **/example** in the database.

when I load the Page on the live server **"*[my-url]*/example"** - it loads **/example.php** instead of going to the database.

The only rewrites I have are:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /page_lookup.php [L]
```

the kicker is that the DEV site is on the same server - using the same Apache ... same rewrites .... and IT DOESN'T DO IT!?!?

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this looks like [this question on webmasters stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76541/apache-2-4-loads-image-files-even-without-extension-why). Try adding a `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: That is EXACTLY what it was ... I don't know why it just started following that in the last couple of days - but removing that solved the issue.

Thank you for the insight and the lesson!

Comment: Just to be transparent though - I needed to remove the MultiViews in order to get the desired effect!